# Sql determine rows that dont have value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that returns results like

```
abc   yes
abc   no
cdef  no
cdef  no
cdef  no
xyz   yes
xyz   no
xyz   no
```

sample query

```
with abc as(
select 'abc' as b , 'yes' as a
union all
select  'abc', 'no'
 
union all
select  'cdef', 'no'
union all
select  'xyz', 'no'
union all
select  'xyz', 'no'
)
 select * from abc
```

I want to return results that show accounts and indicate yes if they have a yes in any row and no if they dont so should look like this

```
abc yes
cdf no
xyz yes.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You should really supply column names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple aggregation should do the trick.

```
Select Col1
      ,Col2 = max(Col2)
 From  YourTable
 Group By Col1
```

Comment: that just gives me abc no, cdef no, xyz no

Comment: Check your data and/or any WHERE's   Take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b06a63dd60ce3bbc4aef7e8264dfaaa9